# Count occurrences of strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, apply

Through `R`, I can easily make a data frame containing the frequencies of certain **string patterns** from string lists.

```
library(stringr)
library(tm)
library(dplyr)    
text = c('i am so hhappy happy now','you look ssad','sad day today','noway')
dat = sapply(c('happy', 'sad'), function(i) str_count(text, i))
dat = data.frame(dat)  
dat = dat %>% mutate(Sentiment = (happy)-(sad))
```

As a result, I can have a data frame like this

```
  happy sad Sentiment
1     2   0         2
2     0   1        -1
3     0   1        -1
4     0   0         0
```

In Python, I can assume rest of codes except `sapply()`

```
import pandas as pd
text = ['i am so hhappy happy now','you look ssad','sad day today','noway']
????
dat = pd.DataFrame(dat)
dat['Sentiment'] = dat.apply(lambda c: c.happy - c.sad)
```

What would `????` be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `pd.Series.str.count`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = ['i am so hhappy happy now','you look ssad','sad day today','noway']
df = pd.DataFrame({'text' : text})

df['happy'] = df.text.str.count('happy')
df['sad'] = df.text.str.count('sad')
df['Sentiment'] = df.happy - df.sad

df    
                      text  happy  sad  Sentiment
0  i am so happy happy now      2    0          2
1             you look sad      0    1         -1
2            sad day today      0    1         -1
3                    noway      0    0          0
```

Comment: And, just for even more details, you can construct that `df` above from your `text` list by doing `df = pd.DataFrame([[sentence] for sentence in text], columns=['text'])`

Comment: @Paul There's a simpler way. ;-)

Comment: Ahh, indeed there is!  I probably should have thought of that. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: It is helpful!! Thank you so much!